Accessing the information inside Datatypes/named types in h5py (with python)
Unable to access information stored within datatypes/named types when parsing through a file in h5py with python.
I have been unpacking an h5m file with h5py in python and have run into a problem with accessing the data stored within named types/Datatypes. I am able to parse through my file to identify and separate these named types, but I am at a loss for how to actually read the data inside the datatype.
The named types I'm working with are not recognized as iterable or subscriptable, so I cannot separate information that way. I'm able to see the dtype (ex.
('<f8', (6,)))
but I am not sure how/if I need to use this information. I have tried going through all of the attributes listed with <my_datatype.__ dir__()> and those of <my_datatype.id.__ dir__()>, and still have nothing.
The closest I've gotten is doing
h5py.h5t.open(my_group.id, my_datatype.id.encode())

where my_datatype is a member of the Group my_group, however I get the error message
KeyError: "Unable to open named datatype synchronously (object '\x03' doesn't exist)" 

where 'x03' is the beginning of the byte encryption for my_datatype. I have tried this above formula with the file id and other parent groups of my_datatype in place of my_group, but it still has not worked.
I am simply at a loss and also losing my mind. Do I fundamentally misunderstand how the datatype object works?? Am I missing something so simple??? Is this somehow not even possible??? Any help is more than appreciated.

Show a full example of creating a file, filling it from a structured array, and then reloading it.  From you description it's unclear whether your  problem is with the h5py iterface, or accessing elements in the saved/loaded array.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say what you are doing wrong. However, based on the few lines you shared, I think you're over-complicating it. The h5py syntax to read HDF5 dataset objects is almost identical to numpy arrays. Just like numpy, HDF5/h5py can handle both homogeneous and heterogeneous data (in different datasets).
I wrote a simple example to demonstrate. The 1st half creates 1 dataset of heterogeneous data. (Homogeneous data does not require all of these steps.) It has 3 fields, each with a different datatype type (1 each of ints, floats and strings). First it creates an dtype and empty recarray, then populates each field with np.array data. The array is then written to the HDF5 file. The 2nd half shows how to read the data from the H5 file with h5py.
with h5py.File('SO_78619117.h5','w') as h5w:
    mixed_dt = np.dtype([('ints',int),('floats',float),('strs','S1')])
    mixed_arr = np.empty((10,), dtype=mixed_dt)
    mixed_arr['ints'] = np.arange(10,dtype=int)
    mixed_arr['floats'] = np.arange(10,20,dtype=float)
    mixed_arr['strs'] = np.array([chr(c) for c in range(65,75)]).astype('S1')
    h5w.create_dataset('mixed_ds', data=mixed_arr)

with h5py.File('SO_78619117.h5') as h5r:
    print(h5r['mixed_ds'])
    print('Dataset data:', h5r['mixed_ds'][()])    
    read_mixed_arr = h5r['mixed_ds'][()]
    print('As array:', read_mixed_arr,'\n') 
    print(h5r['mixed_ds']['ints'])
    print(h5r['mixed_ds']['floats'])
    print(h5r['mixed_ds']['strs'])


Thank you for your response. I think I figured out what my problem was, which is how I understood what the datatype object was. Because I've been working with an h5m file which I don't know anything about and which hasn't had fields for the datatype object, it's been difficult even figuring out what information is there.
